# How can I access a parent method within a child class in PHP?

Tags: php, oop

In PHP, how do I access a parent method from within a child class? The method I want to access is an instance method too. I have tried accessing with $this but of course that refers to the class I'm currently in. I don't want to have to duplicate code and don't want to access it statically.

Parent class:

```
    protected function getSearchTerm(){
    return $this->searchTerm;
}
```

Child class:

`protected function getSearchTerm(){
        return parent::getSearchTerm();
    }`

Comment: Have you heard about the special name `parent`? http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.parent.php

Comment: Doesn't work when I use it.

Comment: Child class:
` protected function getSearchTerm(){
  return parent::getSearchTerm();
 }`

Parent class:
 protected function getSearchTerm(){
  return $this->searchTerm;
 }

Comment: @wolf998 , could you update your question with relative code?

Comment: @sectus I have updated the initial post with code snippets from the project

Answer (score 0):

To call a method from the parent-class within a child-class, you can use `parent`:

```
class Base
{
    function somefunc()
    {
        echo "hello";
    }
}
class Derived extends Base
{
    function call_somefunc()
    {
        parent::somefunc();
    }
}

$class = new Derived;
$class->call_somefunc(); //prints "hello"
```

This does work for different instances, meaning that `parent::somefunc()` calls the method in the parent class of a specific instance of `Derived`. So basically:

```
class Base
{
    function somefunc($id)
    {
        echo 'hello ' . $id . "<br />\n";
    }
}
class Derived extends Base
{
    public $id;
    function __construct($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }
    function call_somefunc()
    {
        parent::somefunc($this->id);
    }
}
$class1 = new Derived(1);
$class2 = new Derived(2);
$class1->call_somefunc(); //prints: hello 1
$class2->call_somefunc(); //prints: hello 2
```

Comment: Why would this not work for me?
**Class b**:
`
 protected function getSearchTerm(){
  parent::getSearchTerm();
 }
`

**Class A**:
`
 protected function getSearchTerm(){
  return $this->searchTerm;
 }
`

Class B inherits from Class A

Comment: @wolf998 How is it not working? Have you debugged it to see if the parent-method gets called at all? Do you get any return value? (Also, right now you aren't doing anything with the value returned in the child-class. Try `echo`ing it or something.)

Comment: Yeah, the property in the parent method is set and I have checked this by dumping "here" inside, when I echo the property it has the value but just doesn't return the value.

Comment: protected function getSearchTerm(){
  print $this->searchTerm;
  return $this->searchTerm;
 }
When printing $this->searchTerm; it has the value, but when calling the method it doesn't return anything

Comment: @wolf998 Wait, I don't quite understand - Does `var_dump($this->searchTerm)` give anything inside the parent-method, and does `var_dump(parent::getSearchTerm())` give anything in the child-method? The property might be set, but in neither of what you're doing has to do with setting it.  You are trying to get it. EDIT: Oh, you showed me the first one. Then just try debugging it with `var_dump(parent::getSearchTerm())`.

Comment: Using var_dump returns NULL.

Comment: @wolf998 How does yours differ from this: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/dc207ecbb0b9f6d885e5106e3cd584303981b86b ? You are aware that both methods are `protected`, right? And protected methods have a restricted visibility.

Comment: For the downvoter: I made a mistake when trying to prove that it calls the same instance. Of course, that output would appear even if it didn't, due to how it passes the ID as an argument.